# Merging arrays in JavaScript not working

Tags: javascript

When I try `var a = ar_url2.concat(ar_desc2);` to join my arrays into one it returns null.  I'm sure it's trivial but I spent a few hours stuck on this now and an explanation as why this is happening would be great. In my code bellow I tried `while(ar_url2.length)a.push(ar_url2.shift());` and it returns same null...

```
  function agregar() {

    var i = 0,
        textarea;
    var ar_desc = [];
    while (textarea = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[i++]) {
        if (textarea.id.match(/^desc_([0-9]+)$/)) {
            ar_desc.push(textarea.id);
        }
    }

    var desc_count_demo = document.getElementById('desc_count').value;
    var desc_count = desc_count_demo - 1;

    i = 0;
    var ar_desc2 = [];
    var campo = null;
    while (i <= desc_count) {

         campo = document.getElementById(ar_desc[i]).value;
        ar_desc2[ar_desc[i]] = campo;
        i++;
    }


    i = 0;
        var input;
    var ar_url = [];
    while (input = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[i++]) {
        if (input.id.match(/^url_([0-9]+)$/)) {
            ar_url.push(input.id);
        }
    }

    var url_count_demo2 = document.getElementById('url_count').value;
    var url_count2 = url_count_demo2 - 1;

   i = 0;
    var ar_url2 = [];
    while (i <= url_count2) {

         campo = document.getElementById(ar_url[i]).value;
        ar_url2[ar_url[i]] = campo;
        i++;
    }


  //  var a = Array.prototype.concat.call(ar_url2, ar_desc2);
     while (ar_url2.length) a.push(ar_url2.shift());

    function url(data) {
        var ret = [];
        for (var d in data)
        ret.push(encodeURIComponent(d) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(data[d]));
        return ret.join("&");

    }
  window.open('alta1.php?'+url(a));
}
```

EDIT: If I pass to function url(ar_url2) or url(ar_desc2) the returned values in the URL are

```
http://localhost/proj1/alta1.php?url_0=inpit&url_1=input
```

and

```
 http://localhost/proj1/alta1.php?desc_0=input&desc_1=input
```

But still cannot merge both into one...

Comment: Tip: http://jsbeautifier.org/

Comment: Can you add a fiddle? One of your arrays probably has malformed data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing I see is your ar_url Array is filled by:

```
while(input=document.getElementsByTagName('input')[i++]){
  if(input.id.match(/^url_([0-9]+)$/)){
    ar_url.push(input.id);
  }
}
```

Since you the putting the whole `id` in the array, it will be filled with things like: `'url_0'`, `'url_1'`, `'url_2'`, etc...

Later you do:

```
  ar_url2[ar_url[i]] = campo;
```

When you index into `ar_url`, you get out the `'url_XXX'` strings.  That means you are setting the `'url_XXX'` properties on `ar_url2` instead of filling in the elements of the array.

Try changing your second loop to:

```
while(input=document.getElementsByTagName('input')[i++]){
  var result;
  if(result = input.id.match(/^url_([0-9]+)$/)){
    ar_url.push(+result[1]);
  }
}
```

To use the value captured in the `([0-9]+)` portion of the RegExp instead of the entire `'url_XXX'` string.

Comment: It does, too, take an array as the first parameter.  `[1, 2, 3].concat( [4, 5, 6] )` is equal to `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`

Comment: I agree with the rest of your post, though.

Comment: Thanks for handling that like an adult, unlike some on here.